# How to find ES6 code using gulp-eslint (error only es6 code -no other rules needed)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, gulp-eslint

```
 gulp.task('lint', () => {

  return gulp.src(['**/*.js'])
               .pipe(eslint({
                 rules: {'rule1': 1,'rule2': 2},
                 envs: [{ "es6": false }]
        }))
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});
```

In some cases, Except ES6 code, I am not interested to know any other errors. Only I wanted to find ES6 code in my directory and clear them out.

Comment: Why not put all your ES6 code under a directory to separate it from old JS or from TS? Or naming them `file.es6.js`?

Comment: Actually, I don't need any ES6 code in my project. Many developers unknowingly commit with ES6 syntax. I wanted to find them during gulp task.

Comment: You could add uglify js to your gulp pipeline and any ES6 will break the build

Comment: Is it NOT possible to find the es6 code with 'eslint' ? since i already use 'eslint' in my project. I also want to find es6 code in my bower_components (some Polymer component)

Comment: I don't think so no, here's the reference https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/3686#issuecomment-350390141
Seems like they use rules to prevent any es6 features